# Direct sum and proof writing with equivalences

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Here's a small exercise I'm working on :

> Let $E$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space and $f\in\mathcal{L}(E)$ verifying $f^2-5f+6Id_E=0$.
> Show that $E=\ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_E)\bigoplus \ker(f-3\mathrm{id}_E)$.

Here's a shorthand proof I'm trying to write :

> Let $x\in E$ and $y\in \ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_E)$ ($y$ exists since $\ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_E))$ is a vector space, thus contains $0_E$).
> $\begin{equation}
>   \begin{split}
> x-y\in \ker(f-3\mathrm{id}_E)
> &\Leftrightarrow f(x-y)=3(x-y) \\
> &\Leftrightarrow f(x)-f(y)=3x-3y \\
> &\Leftrightarrow f(x)-2y=3x-3y \text{ (because $f(y)=2y$)}\\
> &\Leftrightarrow y=3x-f(x)
> \end{split}
> \end{equation}$

> Thus, $\forall x\in E, \exists!y\in \ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_E)$ such that $x-y\in \ker(f-3\mathrm{id}_E)$.
>  Eventually $E=\ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_E)\bigoplus \ker(f-3\mathrm{id}_E)$.

This feels wrong because I've never used the property that $f^2-5f+6\mathrm{id}_E=0$.
Thus I suspect at least one of my equivalences above is false and should be a simple implication (this is backed up by less direct proof I've written that finds the necessary form of $y$, then I need the relation with $f$ to prove this form is a solution).

Unfortunately, I can't convince myself which one of these equivalences is a mistake.
Any hint ? Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1 : there was a typo at the start of the proof near the first $x-y$ (changed $\ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_E)$ into $\ker(f-3\mathrm{id}_E)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f^2-5f+6\mathrm{id}_E=(f-3\mathrm{id}_E)(f-2\mathrm{id}_E)$.

You start incorrectly.
You assume $x\in E$ and $y\in\ker(f-\mathrm{id}_E)$. I do not see why you assume $y\in \ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_E)$.

What you have to prove is the equality of the sets $E$ and $\ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_E)\oplus\ker(f-3\mathrm{id}_E)$.

For that you have to (or can) prove

1. $E\subseteq \ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_E)\oplus\ker(f-3\mathrm{id}_E)$ and
2. $E\supseteq \ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_E)\oplus\ker(f-3\mathrm{id}_E)$.

To show the first implication you assume $x\in E$ and show that $x\in \ker(f-2\mathrm{id}_E)\oplus\ker(f-3\mathrm{id}_E)$.

So there is no second variable involved.

One implication is trivial. Which one?

For the nontrivial one use that $f^2-5f-\mathrm{id}_E=0$. This means that for every $x\in E$ we have $f(x)^2-5f(x)-6=0$. Now use the mentioned factorization.

Comment: The start of my proof comes from a general simless method i've been taught to prove two vector spaces are supplementary :
$E=F\bigoplus G \Leftrightarrow \forall x\in E, \exists!y\in F/x-y\in G$.
This is part of other methods to prove two sets are equal, alongside $E=F\bigoplus G\Leftrightarrow (F\cap G={0}$ and $E=F+G)$ (for direct sum/supplementary spaces) and $E=F\Leftrightarrow (E\subset F$ and $F\subset E)$ (for any sets).

Comment: I do not understand your notation. What do you mean by $E\in F$ and $F\in E$ for example? This $\in$-relation seems to me just an other way to say $E\subseteq F$ or $F\subseteq E$. The other "method" is just the definition of the direct sum, and the notation of your first method I do not understand. What do you mean by $F/x-y\in G$ for example.

Comment: I used $\in$ incorrectly (which is when an element is in a set) compared to $\subset$ for subsets. || In France, we use $/$ to be read as "such that". That reads : $E=F\bigoplus G \Leftrightarrow \forall x\in E, \exists!y\in F$ such that $x-y\in G$.

Comment: The main reason why i want to understand why my posted proof isn't rigorous is double : 1) i'm used to the other types of proofs, that split the work into two pieces. 2) this equivalence method gives the existence and the uniqueness in one go.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof works, let me write it more properly:

We know that if $F$ and $G$ are subspaces of $E$, then $E = F \oplus G$ if and only if for each $x \in E$ there exists a unique $y \in F$ such that $x-y \in G$. Thus, for each $x \in E$, define $y$ as $3x-f(x)$, and note that:

- $y \in \ker(f-2\operatorname{id}_E)$ because $f^2(x)-5f(x)+6x=0$ (since $f^2-5f+6\operatorname{id}_E=0$) implies that $$f(y) = 3f(x)-f^2(x) = 3f(x)+ \big(\!\!-5f(x)+6x\big) = 2y;$$
- $x-y \in \ker(f-3\operatorname{id}_E)$ because $$f(x-y) = f\big( f(x)-2x \big) = f^2(x)-2f(x) = \big(5f(x)-6x\big)-2f(x) = 3(x-y).$$

Thus, for each $x \in E$ there exists $y \in \ker(f-2\operatorname{id}_E)$ such that $x-y \in \ker(f-3\operatorname{id}_E)$. Now, it remains to prove the uniqueness, and that's it.

Comment: The point of my attempt is trying to write a proof that gathers the existence and uniqueness with equivalences. As stated as a comment to Cornman's reply, i've used other methods that all rely on splitting the work between uniqueness and existence. I really want to try and get both at the same time. That's why i really want to understand which equivalence in my original's post reasoning fails,